# Function to determine if adjacent elements are alike

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been stuck on this for a while and I keep running into problems, I'm trying to create a function that returns true if at least one pair of adjacent elements in a list are equal.

Test cases:

[1, 2, 3] -> False

[1, 2, 2, 3] -> True

[2, 6, 3, 6] -> False

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd'] -> True

```
def equal_adjacent_elements(l):
    for x in range(len(l)):
        if l[x] == l[x+1] or l[x] == l[x-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problems I run into are assertion errors and I believe it's because of my loop. Once I find a pair that is equal the returned value won't stay the same because my loops will evaluate the next values in the list. So I just need to find at least one pair, I don't know how I would do that though.

Comment: Is there a wrap around here? Or not?

Comment: as for me you shouldn't do `else: return False` but use `return False` after `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I made few changes. It should work now.

```
def equal_adjacent_elements(l):
    for x in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[x] == l[x+1]:
            return True
    return False
```

or, shorter one using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any),

```
def equal_adjacent_elements(l)
    return any( l[x] == l[x+1] for x in range(len(l)-1) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the list with itself offest by `1` and use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to short-cut the find-one pattern:

```
def equal_adjacent_elements(l):
    return any(x == y for x, y in zip(l, l[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. the indices can run into overflow here;
2. you immediately return `False` from the moment there are two consecutive elements that are not equal, you should return `False` after the `for` loop.

The index problem here is that `x` ranges from `0` to (excluding) `len(l)`. So that means `x-1` ranges from `-1` (which is the last element of the list) to `len(l)-1` and `x+1` from `1` to `len(l)` (including). But the list is not that long, so you get an index out of the list bounds, which is an error.

A more Pythonic approach however is to use a `zip(..)` over the list `l`, and the "*tail*" of the list (the list omitting the first element). So `zip(l, l[1:])`.

We can iterate over every pair `x,y` of `l` and `l[1:]`. In case `x == y`, then we have such element and return `True`.

In case we fail to find such pair, we eventually return `False.

So a correct implementation is:

```
def equal_adjacent_elements(l):
    for x,y in zip(l, l[1:]):
        if x == y:
            return True
    return False
```

Python however has a builtin `any`, that will return `True` from the moment the iterable we give it contains at least one `True`; and `False` if no element has truthiness `True`.

So we can convert the above code to something using the `any` builtin:

```
def equal_adjacent_elements(l):
    return any(x == y for x,y in zip(l, l[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda new to python but anyways hoped this is easy enough

```
def equal_adjacent_elements(l):
    try:
        for i in range(0, len(l)):
            if l[i] == l[i+1]:
                return True
    except IndexError:
        return False
```